# Gratis software for designing sketchnotes

Tags: gratis, windows-10, offline, drawing, sketch

I'm a trainer, so I do workshops etc. I have only technical background and my presentations are probably boring. I have now seen someone doing [sketchnoting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sketchnoting) and it was really impressive, so I'm gonna try that myself.

I'll hardly need to do sketchnoting in live classrooms, so I have time to prepare the "notes" in advance. Thus I'm not sure yet, whether I need to do that with pen and paper or there is also a way to do it fully electronically.

I am looking for

- a sketchnoting software
- for [windows-10](/questions/tagged/windows-10)
- [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis)
- that works with a touch sensitive stylus graphics pad (like those from Wacom)

I expect

- high resolution, so I can print the notes if needed. I think of DIN A4 in 300 dpi.
- palette support, i.e. not 16M colors, but like pencils, you only have a few colors.
- very good undo/redo support.
- at least 2 layers, one for the pencil layer ("blueprint") and one for the ink pen.
- fully [offline](/questions/tagged/offline), no cloud involved

I am aware of [Adobe Sketch](https://www.adobe.com/products/sketch.html), but AFAIK, that's for Android and iOS only.